# How to display the object names in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, console

**How to display the reference variable name of an instance of an object?**

I want to display the following.

---

John has the following cars:

mercedes

prado

---

Here's my code. How can I fix that?

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person John = new Person();
            Car mercedes = new Car();
            Car prado = new Car();
            John.AddCar(mercedes);
            John.AddCar(prado);

            Console.WriteLine("John has the following cars:");
            foreach (Car car in John.Cars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nameof(car));   // not working
            }
        }
}

class Person
{
        public List<Car> Cars { get; set; } = new List<Car>();

        public void AddCar(Car arg)
        {
            arg.Owner = this;
            Cars.Add(arg);
        }

}

class Car
{    
        public Person Owner { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: By adding a `Manufacturer`, `Model`, or similar property to `Car`. Your current approach is incorrect.

Comment: We'll need to know what "doesn't work" means.  Is there an exception thrown?  A compiler error?

Comment: it prints `car` instead of `prado` or `mercedes`

Comment: You see `car` variable in `foreach (Car car in John.Cars)` is not the same varibale as `mersedes` or `prado`, `car` doesn't know anything about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add model (or something) as a property to your car class:

```
class Car
{   
    public Car(string model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }

    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }    
}
```

and then construct your person like this:

```
Person John = new Person();
John.AddCar(new Car("mercedes"));
John.AddCar(new Car("prado"));
```

and print the output like this:

```
foreach (Car car in John.Cars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.Model);
}
```

In short: variable names should be used for you, as a programmer, to help you write your code in a way that lets you read it back easily. It should not be used for user-facing output (generally).

`nameof()` is a convenience executed at compile time, useful for error messages and such. It does not follow the variable in lists, etc. so when you do `foreach (Car car in John.Cars)` the variable name *is* `car`.

Comment: I've provided essentially the same answer as Ashkan, but with more information, and I've received a downvote whereas he's received two upvotes (one from me). That seems logical.

Comment: @MyoThura You can also overwrite ToString, e.g. `public override string ToString() { return Model; }` so that you can just write `Console.WriteLine(car);`. Providing a proper ToString method also helps during debugging to easily identify instances.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a name property to Car:

```
class Car
{    
    public Person Owner { get; set; } 
    public string Name {get; set;}   
}

Car mercedes = new Car {Name = "Mercedes"};
John.AddCar(mercedes);
John.AddCar(new Car { Name = "Prado" });

foreach (Car car in John.Cars)
{
     Console.WriteLine(car.Name);   // not working
}
```